# What makes an answerable question "Use PostgreSQL as a storage engine in MySQL?" "not a real question"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Use PostgreSQL as a storage engine in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287575/use-postgresql-as-a-storage-engine-in-mysql)

The question is closed as "not a real question". The idea to use PostgreSQL as MySQL storage engine is not new and there is an existing (experimental) implementation of the idea: http://www.pinaraf.info/2013/03/my-post-engine-a-postgres-engine-for-mysql/

Have closers only not understood, that mysql is just a "top layer" of an rdbms, or is there something formally wrong with the question so it should be edited or asked again differently?

Comment: Links on the technical subject: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pluggable-storage-overview.html, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/custom-engine.html. The MySQL is a widely supported SQL "frontend" and PostgreSQL also includes an ACID safe storage backend. The idea of the question is far from being stupid.

Comment: The "not a real question" close reason used to be a bit of a catch-all for many bad questions that weren't welcome here. A better reason by today's standards would be "too broad."

Comment: Good to know. Is there btw a way to open/answer closed questions? The question at hand comes up in google, but the accepted answer is not addressing the solution but why not to have one.

Comment: I guess it would still be too broad today I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe "How to use PostgreSQL as storage engine in MySQL?". Specific enough?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/165773

Comment: @jkj I think your major problem here is that the post body doesn't really ask the same question as the title does. The body never asks "how" but mostly just seeks discussion about "why not"; so your title alteration doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @animuson true. It is not a well phrased question. I quess that questions like "How to use innodb as mysql storage engine" would also be closed if the question didn't include a problem to solve. Questions like "How to implement a new MySQL storage engine on berkeley db" would be closed because answering the question would require implementing the software making the question too broad and unsuitable for Q&A format.